# Subclassed NSManagedObject ManagedContext Empty Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I see my subclassed NSManagedObject objects available in the intellisense. I'm trying to figure out how to use them for saving/loading. There's a managedcontext property available which I assume allows me to do that. However the property is readonly and on startup this value is nil. How do I go about using these instances to save/load?

Answer (score 0):

So those entity objects are not initialized upon startup (They are tag as being optional). They can be instantiated by the managed context from app delegate or if you have entity objects saved in Core Data already.